# how to find start date and end date of all weeks present in a month in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to find the start date and end date of all weeks present in a month.
Currently suppose I am having this

```
MAR-17
APR-17
MAY-17
JUN-17
```

I want

```
Month   Week_start_date   Week_start_date

MAR-17  06-MAR-17         12-MAR-17
MAR-17  13-MAR-17         19-MAR-17
MAR-17  20-MAR-17         26-MAR-17
MAR-17  27-MAR-17         02-APR-17

APR-17  03-APR-17         09-APR-17
APR-17  10-APR-17         16-APR-17
APR-17  17-APR-17         23-APR-17
APR-17  24-APR-17         30-APR-17

MAY-17  and so on 
JUN-17
```

I have tried

```
select to_char(to_date('06-AUG-17' ), 'iw' )from dual ;
```

But it gives the week_start_date based on a particular date , But I want the week_start_date for each months .
If week_start_date is found then I only need to add +7 to get week_end_date .
Can anyone please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Add more months in `m` table, or replace it with your actual table. 
I am assuming that `MAR-17` is in varchar data type. If not, replace `to_date(mon,'MON-YY')` with `mon` in the code everywhere.

```
SELECT mon,
       TRUNC(to_date(mon,'MON-YY'), 'iw') + nxt AS iso_week_start_date ,
       TRUNC(to_date(mon,'MON-YY'), 'iw') + 6 + nxt AS iso_week_end_date
FROM
  (SELECT LEVEL*7 - 7 AS nxt
   FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=6)
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 'MAR-17' AS mon
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'APR-17'
   FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 'MAY-17'
   FROM dual
   ) m --Sample data. Replace with original table and change column mon to your `char` column.
WHERE --where clause to filter out of month dates.
    to_date(mon,'MON-YY') <= TRUNC(to_date(mon,'MON-YY'), 'iw') + nxt --iso_week_start_date
  AND last_day(to_date(mon,'MON-YY')) >= TRUNC(to_date(mon,'MON-YY'), 'iw') + nxt --iso_week_start_date
ORDER BY 2
```

Explanation:

- `select TRUNC (sysdate, 'IW') from dual`
  Returns first day of the week (monday) of the given date.
- (select  level*7 - 7 as nxt from dual connect by level <=6) It will
  geneate column in range of 0,7,14,21,28,35 .Later cross join it to multiply each month 6 times to generate 6 different weeks.
- Utilize this while adding `days` to the fist week.
- Where clause is used to filter `out of boundry` dates.

Comment: Thanks @Utsav !! Thanks for the explanation too !!

Comment: Hi @Utsav !! Just a beginner doubt .It would be really helpful of you can share the thought process you used to finalise the logic .More specifically I want to know how did you arrive at the 'out of boundary' condition

Comment: f you know how to calculate the start of the week, you can add 6 days to it for end day. Increment both by 7 with help of cross join. So cross join with `level` gives you this range and 6 output for 1 input. Now if you add 31 to any day, you will cross the current month.. Also `TRUNC(to_date(mon,'MON-YY'), 'iw')` will give you previous month date. Hence we need to take care of out of boundary.

Comment: Also if the answer worked for you, don't forget to `accept` it by clicking on the `tick` on left of the answer, so the question could be closed.

Comment: yes Now it is clear to me . Thanks a ton ! Also i have accepted it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT day_of_month Week_start_date, day_of_month + 6 week_end_Date
FROM 
 (SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE ('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Day') + 1 day_of_month
  FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT   TRUNC (TO_DATE ('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + LEVEL,'Day')+ 1 day_of_month
  FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365)
ORDER BY day_of_month;
```

**Explanation**

Assumptions:

- Number of days in  a year is 365
- First Day of Month is Monday

  ```
    1 SELECT DISTINCT day_of_month Week_start_date, day_of_month + 6 
      week_end_Date
    2  FROM 
    3  (SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE ('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Day') + 1 day_of_month
        FROM DUAL
    4  UNION ALL
    5  SELECT   TRUNC (TO_DATE ('01/01/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + LEVEL,'Day')+ 1 day_of_month
    FROM DUAL
   6 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365)
   7 ORDER BY day_of_month;
  ```

  *Line 5-6* :

  - Generate all the dates from 01 Jan 2017 to 31 Dec 2017  in a 
             year using Connect by Level clause.
  - For the dates that are generated find out the first day of the week using TRUNC function with 'Day' fmt filter.
  - Since the TRUNC functions takes Sunday as the start of the week, hence add 1 to it to get the date corresponding to Monday. With this we get the Mondays' dates for all the days of the year other than 01st Jan 2017.

*Line 3*

- Get the Monday date corresponding to the 01 Jan 2017

  *Line 1*

  - Get the distinct Monday dates and give it an alias of Week_Start_date. Add 6 days to it get the  Week_end_Date

Comment: Hi Vishad , Could you please explain the logic ?

Comment: Hi Joe, added the explanation to the query. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Vishad ! Thanks for the explanation ! Could you please clarify "Get the Monday date corresponding to the 01 Jan 2017" ?

Comment: Also this line please "With this we get the Mondays' dates for all the days of the year other than 01st Jan 2017."